# influxdb query: specify or filter tag by regex

Tags: regex, influxdb

According to the [docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.2/query_language/data_exploration/#regular-expressions), we can...

> Use a regular expression to specify a tag with a value in the WHERE clause.

When I query my influxdb like this, I get the desired results.

`> SELECT "field" FROM "measurement" WHERE tag = 19`

When replacing the where filtering by a regex, however, I get no results.

`> SELECT "field" FROM "measurement" WHERE tag =~ /19/`

Can someone tell me why that is?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found the mistake myself...

I had both a field and a tag with the same key. So I was doing

`> SELECT "filed_key" from "measurement" WHERE field_key =~ /val/`

Now I have changed my schema so that **keys across fields and tags are unique**, and everything works as expected.

There's also a discussion about this phenomenon on [github](https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues/2615).

Answer (score 0):

Regex using Flux Query for InfluxDB 2.0.

src: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/query-data/flux/regular-expressions/

The following example excludes records that do not have _percent in a field key.

> from(bucket: "example-bucket")
> |> range(start: -15m)
> |> filter(fn:(r) =>
> r._measurement == "mem" and
> r._field =~ /_percent/   )